# node js window object

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

On the browser the global object is `window object`, and in `nodejs` the global object is `global object`.

when I run this code using `nodejs` on the terminal i had this output

`console.log(this === global)` ===> this return false

And then using the interactive mode of nodejs

`>this === global`

`true`

But on the browser both `console.log` and `this === window` returns `true`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you **a part of the answer** :

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a
>   global variable. In Node this is different. **The top-level scope is not
>   the global scope**; var something inside a Node module will be local to
>   that module.

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

But i don't know why the top level scope is the global scope in interactive mode.